# Can you make your ally die faster when trying to save him from a Death Ray?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, saving-throw

The Beholder has the Death Ray power. It says that if the target fails the second saving throw, the target dies.

Does it count for when the players are using heal or powers to let their ally save from the effect? Cause in that case, he could die even faster.

Is there any paragraph in any of the books that makes it clear?

Comment: Note that this was a bug in 4e as initially released, in that the original PHB and DMG seemed to assume that failing a saving throw was harmless, so a bonus saving throw was a great thing to get.  "First failed save" mechanics broke this assumption.

Comment: I just noticed this question is actually a [duplicate](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2981/12011).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.

The Player's Handbook 2, page 219 has this to say on the matter (emphasis mine):

> **Failed Saving Throw:** Sometimes an effect changes as a target fails saving throws against it. The new effect, specified in a “First Failed Saving Throw” or a “Second Failed Saving Throw” entry, takes effect after the target fails a saving throw against the previous
>   effect at the end of the target’s turn. *The effect doesn’t change if the creature fails a saving throw against it at a time other than the end of its turn.*

Comment: Or maybe there is a distinction between saving throws. Welcome to the site, nice first answer, and good catch. I completely missed that.

Comment: This can also be found in the Rules Compendium on page 98. It also has an example. I think I'm going to ask a similar question about death saving throws.